# What does " = " instead of " == " mean in c if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   int b = 10,a;
      if (a = 5){
         printf("%d",b);
      }
   }
```

In the above program if statement always returns true even if i change the data type of the variable "a" from "int" to "char".

What does = mean in the if statement??

Comment: Same as always, assignment.

Comment: Is this actual code or part of a test? Because in any other case, it means there is a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is an `assignment operator` in C. According to C99 6.5.16:

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the
>   left operand. **An assignment expression has the value of the left
>   operand after the assignment, but is not an lvalue.**

It means that expression `a = 5` will return `5` and therefore instructions inside `if` block will be executed. In contrary, if you replaced it with `a = 0` then `0` would be returned by assignment expression and instructions inside `if` would not be executed.

Answer (score 2):

A single = means an assignment operator, that means you are changing the value of *a* and using this value in the if statement.

```
if(a = 5) {
// some code
}
```

is the same of:

```
a = 5;
if(a) {
// some code
}
```

The == means a operation of logical equivalence, witch will return 1 if the two values are the same or 0 if they aren't the same.

Answer (score 1):

The single `=` will assign the value 5 to `a`. Assignment will evaluate true if the assignment value evaluates true (i.e. not 0, null etc). If it evaluates true, the  function will branch into the `if` statement block. And there's the side effect that `a` gets value 5.

Comment: Assignment won't always evaluate true, e.g. `if (a = 0)` won't branch.

Comment: but what is i change the data type to "char"?? will the assignment condition be true in that case also because in this case i m assigning integer to a char type variable

Comment: a=65 yields 'A' and returns true; a=0 yields '\0' and returns false

Comment: @user3542577: It doesn't really matter what type is there. If result of the assignment is non-zero, it will branch.

Comment: @dreamlax: I changed the "always aveluates true" to process your valid comment. `a=5` evaluates true, but `a=0` would indeed evaluate false.

Answer (score 1):

- Assignment operator returns the assigned value back.
- "if" statement decides to true if checked value is other than zero

So:

- "if (a=0)" returns false
- "if (a=x) where x!= 0" returns true

Thus you should use "==" operator in the if statement as other friends told.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in C it is allowed in a boolean expression to use the assignment operator. Because of that = as assignment must be a different symbol than = for comparisson.

Because in a language such as BASIC there can be no confusion of whether the programmer means assignment or comparisson, BASIC uses the same symbol for the two meanings:

C:

```
if ((a=5)==5) ...        // a is set to 5 and then compared to 5
```

Basic:

```
a = 5                    ' assignment
If (a = 5) Then          ' comparison
```