# C function still INVALID number

Tags: c

```
       #include <stdio.h>
        int main() {
            /*function declaration*/
    
        double invalidInput(double);
        int loop_obeTask;
        double  obe_Task[3];
        double checkInput ;
        for(loop_obeTask = 1 ; loop_obeTask < 4 ; loop_obeTask++)
        {
            printf("OBE%d : ", loop_obeTask);
            scanf("%lf",&obe_Task[loop_obeTask]);
        
            checkInput = invalidInput(obe_Task[loop_obeTask]);
            if(checkInput = 1)
            {
                  printf("INVALID INPUT \n" );
                  break;
            }
        }
           return 0;
        }
    double invalidInput(double inputGrade)
    {
        double indicator;
    
        if(inputGrade > 100)
        {
            indicator = 1;
        }
        else{
            indicator = 0;
        }
        return indicator;
    }
```

Hello Guys, want to validate the input numbers using the function once the user enters > 100 IT IS INVALID INPUT but in my case, it always shows invalid input both greater and less than 100. I can't post image because my reputation less than 10.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG85e.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZGlL.png)

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images. And please choose one language tag: c and c# are very different languages.

Comment: Not your problem, but: since `invalidInput()` returns a 0/1, true/false result, it's strange (and arguably wrong) for it to return a `double`.

Comment: Your actual problem, as @mikyll98 has identified, is an easy-to-make mistake, and one that a good compiler will warn you about.  See if you can use a more modern compiler, or turn up the warning level on the one you have.

Comment: Another problem: your loop `for(loop_obeTask = 1; loop_obeTask < 4; loop_obeTask++)` is mismatched with your array `double  obe_Task[3]`.  Remember that arrays are 0-based in C.

Comment: There's certainly a canonical dup for this question.  Anyone know how to find it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What does "=" instead of "==" mean in if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374563)

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer

You're not checking the value, but assigning it: `if(checkInput = 1)`

You should use the `==` operator instead.

#### Long answer

Even if it does compile, your code presents numerous conceptual mistakes:

- You're using `double` as return value of `invalidInput()`. Since that function is for validation only and it returns either 1 or 0, you should use `int` as return type instead.
- Your `for` loop starts at index number 1, which is wrong and will lead to *undefined behaviour*. C array indexes starts at 0, so if you define an array with size 3, the available indexes are going to be 0, 1, 2, and the loop should look something like `for (index = 0; index < MAX; index++)` where `MAX` is 3 in this case.
- Your `if` condition is not checking the equality of `checkInput` and `1`. That's because you're using the assignment operator `=`, instead of the equality operator `==`.
- It's common practice to put your function declarations at the top of your file and before the `main` definition, both for readability and scope reasons.